# Solving $\log_2(x+1)+x=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, closed-form

Here's the equation I'd like to solve:
$$\log_2\left(x+1\right)+x=2$$
Now I am aware that there's only one solution to the equation by graphing $y=-x+2$ and $y=\log_2\left(x+1\right)$.

The question is: **how do you know the solution is $x=1$**? Is there any other appraoch besides guessing?

---

Please note that I know how to prove there's only one solution. What I'd like to know is the process of finding the solution $x=1$.

Comment: Even the best methods of algebraic simplification will lead to some form of $f(x)2^{f(x)} = a$, where, now elementary methods (other than intuition and guessing) cannot be used.

Comment: Any proof or theorems needed to understand the conclusion 'now elementary methods (other than intuition and guessing) cannot be used'? BTW I think you may mean $f\left(x\right)\cdot2^{g\left(x\right)}=a$ instead of $f(x)2^{f(x)} = a$.

Comment: The same trick repeats again and again. $y=\log_2(x+1)+x$ is an increasing function... Then you cut it by $y=2$.

Comment: See the Lambert-W function. Also, if you manipulate the equation correctly, $f(x) = g(x)$ is possible, where we can now apply Lambert-W function to solve. I meant $f(x)e^{f(x)} = a$

Comment: There are other complex solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align}&\log_2\left(x+1\right)+x=2
\\\\&\implies \log_2(x+1)+x+1=3
\\\\&\implies \log_2(x+1)+\log_2(2^{x+1})=\log_2(2^3)
\\\\&\implies (x+1)2^{x+1}=8
\\\\&\implies (x+1)e^{(x+1)\ln 2}=8
\\\\&\implies (x+1)\ln2\cdot e^{(x+1)\ln 2}=8\ln2\end{align}$$

Here, using [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we have
$$\begin{align} &(x+1)\ln 2=W(8\ln2)
\\\\&\implies x+1=\frac{W(8\ln 2)}{\ln 2}
\\\\&\implies x=\frac{W(4\ln4)}{\ln2}-1=\frac{\ln4}{\ln2}-1 = 1\end{align}$$

where we used the identity $W(x\ln x)=\ln x$ for $x\geqslant e^{-1}$. (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Identities))

Comment: (+1) quite similar to lone student's latest answer,

Comment: I think that I would ultimately accept this answer. Although this is extremely similar to another answer, it clarifies some properties that need to be used more clearly. In any case, thank you to the author of the other answer, @lone student.

Comment: And many thanks to @nonuser for bringing this question back to everyone's attention.

Comment: @ThomasPeng $$W(8\ln 2)=W(\ln 4e^{\ln 4})=\ln 4$$ by *definition* of Lambert $-W$ function, which is clear in my answer. Did you mean that point in unclear in my answer ?

Comment: @lonestudent I wouldn't say your answer is **unclear**, but mathlove's answer explains the substitutions in a more detailed manner as well as gives some eternal links for me to refer to. This could be rather helpful in the cases where I don't know much about Lamber-W function. But thanks you anyway. You two's answers both help me a lot. Upvote for yours too.

Answer (score 4):

$g(x) = \log_2(x+1)$is defined when $x>-1$ and is strictly increasing.  And, $h(x) = x$ is also strictly increasing.

So, $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ must be strictly increasing.

$f(x) = 2$ has at most 1 solution.
$f(1) = 2$ so $f(x) = 2$ has exactly 1 solution.

Comment: Hi there, It would be beneficial if you would explain why you took  $f(x) = 2$.

Comment: I took $f(x) = log_2 (x+1) + x.$  Then the original problem asked for how many values of $x$ does $f(x) = 2$

Comment: Please review my question, it intends to find how do you get $x=1$ instead of why it is the only solution.

Comment: I found it "by inspection."  Suppose there is a solution such that $x$ is a rational number.  Then $\log_2 (x+1)$ is rational.  Then  $x+1 = 2^{\frac pq}$ and start with the easy numbers to check.  $x\in\{-\frac 12, 0, 1, 3\}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\thinspace x+1=u$, then :

$$
\begin{align}&\log_2(x+1)+x+1=3\\
\implies &\log_2(u2^u)=3\\
\implies &u2^u=8\\
\end{align}
$$

Using the substitution $\thinspace 2^u=e^t$, yields :

$$
\begin{align}&\frac {te^t}{\ln 2}=8\\
\implies &te^t=8\ln 2>0\\
&\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace =4\ln 4\\
&\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace =\color{#c00}{\ln4e^{\ln 4}}\\
\implies &t=W(8\ln 2)\end{align}
$$

Then, we reverse all the substitutions :

$$
\begin{align}x=u-1&=\frac {t}{\ln 2}-1\end{align}
$$

Finally, we conclude that :

$$
\begin{align}\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x=\frac {W(8\ln 2)}{\ln 2}-1}\end{align}
$$

which is equal to $1$, since $t=\ln 4\implies x=1\thinspace .$

Comment: (+1) I think this answer is fine. The other answer was basically just putting $x=1$ into the equation and verifying it's a solution

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,
$$1+x=2-(1-x) = 2\left(1+\dfrac{x-1}2\right)\in(0,\infty).$$
Let $\,y=\dfrac{x-1}2,\,$ then
$$1+\log_2(1+y)+1+2y =2,\quad y\in(-1,\infty),$$
$$f(y)=y+\log_2(1+y)=0.$$
If $\,y\in(0, \infty),\,$ then $\,f(y)> 0.$

If $\,y=0,\,$ then $\,f(y)=0.$

If $\,y\in(-1,0),\,$ then $f(y)<0.$

Therefore, $\,y=0,\quad \color{brown}{\mathbf{x=1.}}$

Answer (score 0):

Well, make a graph. Suppose the line AB represnts $y = -x+2$ and the curve CD represents $y = log$<sub>$2$</sub> $(x+1)$. We can see that AB and CD only intersects in the point (1,1). In the point (1,1), x=1; so, x =1 is the only answer. If AB and CD intersected anywhere else, there would have been a different answer. For example if they also intersected on (2,y),  x =2 would have been an answer.

However, AB and CD will never intersect in any other point as *when x → infinity,  y → infinity for CD and y → negative infinity for AB. So, they both are heading to the opposite direction. Again, when x → negative infinity,  y → negative infinity for CD and y → infinity for AB.* so, AB and CD will only intersect on (1,1) and thus, x=1 will be the only answer.

Comment: Yes but my question is how do you know the solution **is** x=1?

Comment: @ThomasPeng you need to plot/draw out some points after which you can make an rough prediction of what might the solution be

Comment: Like for example looking at above graph, I can somewhat estimate that if there was a solution it had to lie between (0,2)... and then by pure guess you can get that x=1 is a solution, but this graphical method shows that whatever solution you got was the only solution to the equation

Comment: @ThomasPeng because AB and CD only intersects in the point (1,1). In the point (1,1), x=1; so, x =1 is the only answer. If AB and CD intersected anywhere else, there would have been a different answer. For example if they also intersected on (2,y),  x =2 would have been an answer. However, AB and CD will never intersect in any other point as *when x → infinity,  y → infinity for CD and y → negative infinity for AB. So, they both are heading to the opposite direction. Again, when x → negative infinity,  y → negative infinity for CD and y → infinity for AB.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the zeros of function
$$f(x)=\frac{\log (x+1)}{\log (2)}+x-2$$
Its first derivative
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1) \log (2)}+1$$ cancels at
$$x_*=-1-\frac{1}{\log (2)}$$ and $f(x_*)$ is a complex number.

For any $x \geq -1$ (which is the domain), $f'(x)>0$. So, only one root.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_2(x+1)+x=2$$
$$(x+1)2^x=4$$
$$\color{red}{\ln2(x+1)}e^{\color{red}{\ln2(x+1)}}=8\ln2$$
$$\ln2(x+1)=W(8\ln2)$$
$$x=\frac{W(4\ln4)}{\ln2}-1.$$
Now, by using the property $W(x\ln x)=\ln x$ for $x\geq e^{-1}$, as mathlove did in his answer, we can show that $x=1$ or alternatively, if calculators are allowed, we can use [Lambert W Function Calculator](https://www.had2know.org/academics/lambert-w-function-calculator.html):

$$\ln2\approx 0.69314718\implies 4\ln4\approx 5.54517744\implies W(4\ln4)\approx 1.386294\implies\\ x\approx 0.99999995\implies x=1$$
for practical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_2\left(x+1\right)+x=2; (x>-1)$$
$\implies \log_2 (x+1)+\log_2 2^x=\log_2 4$
$\implies 2^x.(x+1)=4$
$\implies 2^{t-1}.t=4$ for $(x+1)=t(>0)$
$\implies 2^t.t=8$
Since $f(t)=2^t.t$ is monotonically strictly increasing and positive hence it must intersect $t=8$ at exactly one point. It is easy to verify that the integer (positive) solution $t=2$ is the required value, which implies $x+1=2\implies x=1$.